# cannot detect error. Where is the infinite loop occurring?

Tags: javascript

```js
// JavaScript Document
var person = prompt("GIVE INPUT", "");
var count  = 0;
var array  = person.split(",");
var freq   = [];
var words  = [];

//freq.fill(0);
//words.fill("");
//window.alert(freq[0]);

var i = 0, j = 0;
while (array.length > 0) {
    var temp = array[0];
    while (j < array.length) {
        if (temp == array[j]) {
            count = count + 1;
            array.splice(j, 1);
            //console.log(array);
            j = 0;
        }
        else {
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    freq[freq.length]   = count;
    count               = 0;
    words[words.length] = temp;
}
window.alert(freq + "\n" + words);
```

The problem is that whenever I run it an infinite loop occurs and no output is shown, I cannot find the error please help if possible. This code is for finding the frequency of the words in a input string with words separated by commas. thank u.

Comment: What's your script supposed to do?

Comment: It is always useful to step through code in a debugger.  You will find out what is going on quite easily.

Comment: calculating frequency of words separated by commas in a string-@j08691

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put `var i=0,j=0;` inside the `while` !

```
while(array.length>0)
{var i=0,j=0;
```

[Working fidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enrph7u5/)

Comment: thank you. i did such a silly mistake. sometimes its not detectable. ty a lot man. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting your loop variable j to 0 on each iteration. This condition `if(temp==array[j])` never fails so j is always reset to 0, so `while(j<array.length)` is always true.

Comment: but i am applying array.splice which is reducing the size of the array,, therefore length will become 0 at one time, then the loop should end

Answer (score 0):

After coming out of the inner While loop, you need to reset `j` to zero. As the incremental value of `j` is not allowing it to go again inside the inner loop So `array.length` is not reducing And we are getting an infinite loop.

```js
// JavaScript Document
   var person = prompt("GIVE INPUT", "");
   var count=0;
   var array = person.split(",");
   var freq = new Array();
   var words = new Array();
   //freq.fill(0);
   //words.fill("");
   //window.alert(freq[0]);
   var i=0,j=0;
   while(array.length>0)
   {
    var temp=array[0];
    while(j<array.length)
    {
     if(temp==array[j])
     {
        count=count+1;
     array.splice(j,1);
     //console.log(array);
        j=0;
     }
    else
    {
      j=j+1;
    }
    
    }
    freq[freq.length]=count;
    count=j=0;
    words[words.length]=temp; 
   }
   window.alert(freq+"\n"+words);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but i couldnt accept your answer because it was answered by someone above beforehand. ty :)

Answer (score 0):

It's where **for** is more useful for consistency. You can replace inner **while** loop by this **for** loop:

```
for(j=a.length-1; j>=0; j--)
    if(temp==a[j]) {
        count=count+1;
        a.splice(j,1);
    }
```

Nevertheless, overall complexity of your counting method can be reduced with data structure like map.
Essential part of your script can be reduced to this:

```
var counter = new Map();
for (i in array)
    counter.set(array[i], (counter.get(array[i])||0)+1);
var freq = Array.from(counter.values());
var words = Array.from(counter.keys());
```